# how to set spring.config.location for a gradle spring boot project in Intellij IDEA community version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to configure `spring.config.location` or `spring.config.additional-location` in a Java Spring Boot project using Gradle in my Intellij IDEA community version. It is run in the IDE clicking the little green arrow button, not from command line like `java -jar`.

Basically, we want to add another folder hierarchy under `src/main/resources/config`, to load `src/main/resources/config/a/` and `src/main/resources/config/b/` folder at the same time.

What we have tried all failed:

- set VM options `-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/config/a/`
- pass it to terminal `gradle test` run
- set a Environment variable in `Run configuration` in the IDE "Edit configuration": `spring.config.location=classpath:/config/a/,classpath:/config/b/`

Any idea? I am with community version so there is no Spring Boot support available in the Enterprise or Ultimate version.

"Not working" means that `gradle test` cannot pass.

Comment: How do you run it from command line? and does it work there?

Comment: I run in gitbash(I am on Windows) like `./gradlew test -Dspring...`

Comment: but then setting the VM options must work -Dspring... the same what you do on the command line

Comment: Yes that is weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it through an environment variable:

`SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=classpath:/config/a/,classpath:/config/b/`

Note that "spring.config.location" is the name of the JVM argument but the environment variable is written with uppercase letters and underscores.

EDIT:

I don't know exactly why gradle won't pick up your VM options if you configure it as you described. If you want to run it with `gradle bootRun`, you can add the following to your build.gradle to pass the VM options to the app when running with `bootRun`:

```
bootRun {
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

On the other way, if you want to run it only by clicking the green arrow, maybe you should configure the VM options in the [Gradle settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html) inside IntelliJ.

Comment: I suggest an edit adding a trailing `/` after each path, and yes, it worked! Thanks for making it community wiki. I just don't understand why with gradle project all the runs in Intellij IDEA **only** work with "Environment variables"; it happens as well with `spring.profiles.active`!

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why this doesn't work, I'll post an update when I find what could potentially cause your problems. Btw. how are you configuring the VM options in IntelliJ? I think that the best way to set the VM options for your gradle would be to set it in gradle settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html. Do you have this in your IntellIiJ? I don't know if this is gradle support is available in the Community edition...

Comment: Yes I have these settings, but fiddling around does not give me a solution to the original post. The VM options are previously set as I stated but I don't have `bootRun{}` or `test {}` configurations in `build.gradle`. I will try to add them

Comment: I have tried VM options(like `-Dspring... -Dspring...` with `System.properties` in `test{}` block and it works, too. Thanks! But the wording may seem a little strange, they are vm options not system properties. Yet, the env var approach is better because when we reach CI pipeline, in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, we must pass them as well and maybe setting env var is the only way?

Comment: If setting it as an env var is the best option for you, use it, why not. In my team, we are also using the env variable in our CI pipeline and on our servers where we deploy the app. When running locally, we set the property through VM options with the bootRun task (this way it's not necessary that a new developer has to set the environment variable when running the app and everything is self-contained)..

Comment: To specify jvm options for Gradle process please use [Gradle Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-gradle.html).

Comment: I see your point @Andrey, but that is global Gradle config settings and every project has its own settings. I don't know in the case of conflict what happens, they overwrite? the latter wins? etc.