# Spring Boot + Gradle: take VM options when I run single tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

When I run Gradle tasks like `test` from IntelliJ, I set VM options and/or environment variables *for all tests* in "Edit configuration" dialog and they work. See my question at [how to set spring.config.location for a gradle spring boot project in Intellij IDEA community version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683095/how-to-set-spring-config-location-for-a-gradle-spring-boot-project-in-intellij-i)

Now, if I want to run a single test, I must:

- run test, which fails of course
- edit configuration to add VM options and/or env vars
- run it again

Is there some way to configure the VM options and/or env vars in `build.gradle` so that would be picked up by every single test automatically?

PS: the args are `-Dspring.profiles.active=...` and `-Dspring.config.additional-location`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the system properties in the file **gradle.properties** like so:

```
systemProp.spring.profiles.active=profileName
spring.config.additional-location=additionalLocation
```

[See also: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tarts, but I think I have found one thing maybe better: setting a template of run configuration in IDEA. The question may be reworded into: "can I in some way, not limited in `build.gradle`, to set these variables?"

In "Run Configuration", on the left side, there is a category named "Template" listing all possible categories of tests we can run and providing template for each, where we set universal values for single tests.

[image]

You can see that "Gradle" and "JUnit" and other many categories are listed, so we can change VM options here, then all unit tests are run with this param set.